# Interpreting scaled betas for quadratic terms in a negative binomial regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, quadratic-form

I created a negative binomial model where the final model included 5 quadratic predictors (each with a corresponding linear term). I am considering two ways to interpret the beta coefficients for each predictor: an odds-ratio approach, and reporting the maximum/maxima for the quadratic term using the equation -2a/b where a is the linear term and b is the quadratic term. For example, I may report that animal use was expected to decrease by 10% for every 1 m increase in distance from roads. Or, I may report that animal use was highest at 25 m from roads.

This is simple enough, but prior to model fitting I scaled each response around 0 and with a variance of 1. Two questions: 1) I know how to create odds-ratio estimates using the formula [e(beta)-1]*100 for linear (presumably unscaled) variables. How do I create odds-ratio estimates for scaled quadratic variables? 2) How do I interpret the maximum or maxima for scaled quadratic variables? For example, if I estimate that -2a/b = 25, I assume this doesn't mean that use was highest at 25 m; rather, must I somehow backtransform this estimate to determine the true, unscaled value?